# No overload for 'dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, Series myseries, int multiplier, EventArgs e)
{
  if (datelimitsset == 1) {
    var dt1 = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    chart1.Series.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < multiplier; i++)
    {
      config();
      myseries.Points.AddXY(Convert.ToString(date[i]), Convert.ToDouble(array[i]));
      string[] rowi = { Convert.ToString(date[i]), Convert.ToString(array[i]) };
      dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rowi);
    }
  }
}
```

This is giving me the error:

> No overload for 'dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

I do not fully understand event handlers, can anyone give me advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your handler must have the same signature specified by the [`EventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx) delegate.

That is, you'll have to remove your two middle parameters:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

In terms of a workaround for passing these parameters into the function, you have a few options...

1. Generate the event handler as an anonymous function (as per James' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8981206/33969))
2. Store and retrieve them from instance variables
3. Store them on the DateTimePicker control's `Tag` property and resolve them in the handler

The second option should be obvious enough...

The third option might look like:

```
// In control initialization somewhere
dateTimePicker1.Tag = new DateTimePickerParams() { Series = myseries, Multiplier = multiplier }; // Where DateTimePickerParams is your own private class/struct defined explicitly for this purpose...

private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ctl = sender as DateTimePicker;
    var parameters = ctl.Tag as DateTimePickerParams;

    var mySeries = parameters.Series;
    var multiplier = parameters.Multiplier;

    // Execute...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The signature for `System.EventHandler` is `(object sender, EventArgs e)` so you either need to change your method signature to this:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Or keep your current signature and use a lambda expression as a delegate adapter when you subscribe to the event:

```
dateTimePicker1.ValueChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
 dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender, [your Series variable], [your int multiplier variable], e);
```

When you use a lambda expression as a delegate adapter, you are essentially creating a delegate which conforms to the `System.EventHandler` signature (it is passed an `object` and an `EventArgs` argument), which then calls your original handler method passing all of the arguments required to satisfy your `dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged` method.

The reference documentation for the [System.EventHandler delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx).

EDIT: documentation for an example handler for the [DateTimePicker.ValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.valuechanged.aspx) event

Answer (score 1):

You can't add arbitrary parameters to the event handler like that, the method signature must match the event delegate. How would the `DateTimePicker` know what to pass for the `myseries` and `multiplier` parameters?

Comment: This is what I don't know how to do, as they are in another method which the event handler can't access. Any tips?